# How to make sure I am writing jQuery 1.6

Tags: jquery

I have been using jquery 1.3 and upgraded to jQuery 1.6. However I am not sure if the code I am writing is 1.6 since it's difficult to list the api difference from 1.3 to 1.6.

What would you do in my case? Any techniques you follow?

Comment: The blog is quite helpful. There are release notes going back to 1.3, I would suggest you start reading the earlier entries and work your way to the latest. http://blog.jquery.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are not that many differences and chances are that the code you have written will work exactly the same. Library projects like jQuery are very conscious of backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

If the script tag references jQuery 1.6, you are using jQuery 1.6.

You should be able to write your code basically the same way, but you can look [here](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/03/jquery-16-released/) for breaking changes.